# How to edit the files of an osCmax site

Tags: php, html, oscommerce

I have a website running on osCmax setup by a developer a while back and now I want to restyle some of the pages myself from the markup and CSS only.

I'm familiar with HTML/CSS and some jQuery to an extent but I have never touched any PHP. This is my first time really getting into any of the osCmax pages, site, etc., myself so I am little confused on what it really is or does.

If I want to edit any of the HTML/CSS myself for styling pages will I have to download and login to the osCmax admin panel to get to any of the files?

Or can I just go directly through my server to grab the appropriate HTML and CSS files? Wouldn't all the necessary files from the download be on my server already or is this something that I have to download to use?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is restyle the pages, then just modify the css.  You shouldn't need to modify the PHP (unless parts of your HTML are created with out a class or id).

Answer (score 0):

oscmax has a seperate folder for its template. all you have to do is editing the .css file. but sometimes you need to design the template from scrath and since the OSCMAX is outdated you must edit all the pages with .tmpl prefix.